# How to implement constants across custom resources in Chef?

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, cookbook

I am writing a cookbook that defines four [custom resources](https://docs.chef.io/custom_resources.html). There are multiple constants that should be shared across all of the resources (permissions for certain types of files, prefixes for names, relative paths etc...).

How can I share these constants across multiple custom resources?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put em' in a module under `libraries/default.rb`:

```
module MyCookbook
  BASE_PATH = '/foo'
end

# And then in the resource
property(:path, default: MyCookbook::BASE_PATH)
```

or somesuch.